# PHPexcel Read single cell in xlsx

Tags: php, xls, xlsx, import-from-excel

Ive been trying to wrap my head around using PHPexcel and would like ot know if there is any other simpler solution.

Using PHPexcel i am able to load a standard .xsl file and pick the exact cell i need to import.

```
$code = $data->val(2,2,0);
echo $code
```

Now this works perfectly, it will echo the second cell in the second row without any issues. problem is the spreadsheets i need to parse are all in .xlsx format which PHPexcel does not support.

Is there an alternative to PHPexcel which will allow me to simply extract a single cell in a .xlsx file?

Comment: PHPExcel will parse both xls and xlsx files.... but with syntax like `$code = $data->val(2,2,0);
`, what you're using isn't PHPExcel

Comment: I think it must be an old version. testing 1.8.0 now

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/ That is the code i was using

Comment: So not [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

Comment: Correct, Although i did fix the import using the code listed I will be transferring it all to PHPexcel. Thanks Mark